# Is there a way to add $CONFIG_DIR to the project config when creating a container pod?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

When following [this walkthrough](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk/), a `$CONFIG_DIR` environment variable is used without explicitly setting it. Is there a way to associate this with the project using `gcloud config set` rather than create a local environment variable of that name?

Comment: Update: It turns out that the variable is set in the example, but in the 'prerequisites' section in an expandable sub-section - so it's pretty hard to find. We'll work on updating the docs. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Isn't that section just setting the project id and compute zone? Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You'll need to create a local environment variable. `gcloud config set` is only used for gcloud specific settings, not environment settings. `$CONFIG_DIR` isn't used by gcloud itself, it's used by your shell to expand the files being passed into gcloud.